# Слово "нагинать(ся)"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Было ли когда-нибудь слово "наги**н**ать(ся)" литературным, или им было ***всегда только*** "наги**б**ать(ся)"?

Comment: http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/1394244-kak-pravilno-govorit-nagibatsja-ili-naginatsja.html

Comment: У Лескова в повести "Воительница" в прямой речи главной героини встречается слово "нагинаться", к сожалению, не имею возможности процитировать.

Comment: _Я будто **нагинаюсь**, чтоб поднять палочку, чтоб эту собачку от себя отогнать, а из земли вдруг мертвая ручища..._ https://books.google.ee/books?id=K5Z3BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA220&lpg=PA220&dq=%D1%8F+%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%8C+%D0%9B%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2&source=bl&ots=iT7uhNjiA_&sig=ACfU3U14XVpWFsgxjwmXJuZAZlqYJtXPqg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiS37ay0qPhAhXylIsKHZ3HB5kQ6AEwAXoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D1%8F%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%9B%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2&f=false

Comment: Спасибо, Марина и Римма Михайловна!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

«Не нагибайся так, не нагибайся! Упадёшь!» — говорит мать, следя за действиями пятилетнего сына; «Поправь ковёр, а то мне нагинаться трудно», — обращается бабушка к внучке. «Нагибайся ниже, а то гриба не увидишь», — поучает дед внука. В живой речи мы довольно часто встречаемся с такими выражениями. «А как правильно: “нагибаться” или “нагинаться”?» — спросила я знакомого девятиклассника, усердно осваивающего правила русской грамматики. После паузы последовал неуверенный ответ: «Нагинаться»... Увы, ответ неверный, так что пора поговорить о правильном написании глаголов, которые у многих вызывают затруднения.

Козьма Прутков рекомендовал: «Зри в корень!» Воспользуемся советом классика и вглядимся в корень, в грамматический корень интересующих нас глаголов.

Сначала небольшое отступление. С младых ногтей мы помним: корень — сердцевина слова, начало начал, общая часть основы родственных слов, в которой сосредоточено тождественное для всех родственных слов значение. Образуя слова, одни корни не меняют свой графический облик: двор, дворник, дворецкий, дворовый (-двор-). Другие же способны видоизменяться и выступать в нескольких вариантах. Например, слова собрание, собирать, переберу, выбор — родственники, у этих слов один и тот же корень, но представлен он четырьмя разновидностями: -бр-, -бир-, -бер-, -бор-.

Вооружившись этими сведениями, посмотрим, что за корень в интересующих нас словах, единообразен ли он или имеет варианты: нагнуть / нагибать, разогнуть / разгибать, изогнуться / изгибаться, перегиб, гибкий, загнуть, негибкость, перегнувшись, огибая, согнув, выгибание и т. п.

Чем примечательны эти однокоренные слова? Во-первых, тем, что корня -гин- не встретилось ни в одном из них (а таких однокоренных слов только в Школьном словообразовательном словаре русского языка А. Н. Тихонова более 100!). Во-вторых, тем, что корень в этих словах двуедин, то есть он существует в двух вариантах: -г- (согнуть, нагнуть, разогнуть, перегнуться) и -гиб- (огибать, нагибать, разгибать, загибаться, перегиб, выгибание). В-третьих, каждый из двух названных вариантов появляется в строго определённых случаях: первый — в глаголах совершенного вида (что сделать? — разогнуть, изогнуться, выгнуть, отогнуть), а второй — в глаголах несовершенного вида (что делать? — разгибать, изгибаться, выгибать, отгибать). Вот ларчик и открылся!

Теперь можно уверенно ответить на вопрос: как правильно — «нагибаться» или «нагинаться»? Конечно, нагибаться. Ведь это глагол несовершенного вида (что делать? — нагибаться). И корень в нём -гиб-.

Итак, мы рассмотрели все три варианта одного корня, встречающиеся в живой речи: два первых (-г-, -гиб-) — нормативные, образцовые, а третий (-гин-) — ошибочный, нарушающий правила, принятые в современном языке, недопустимый — значит, лишний. И, как всякий лишний, он просто обязан исчезнуть из нашей речи. Третий должен уйти!

> Лидия Пастухова, автор книги «Этюды о словах» ( Источник: Грамота.ру).

Comment: Спасибо, интересный отрывок!

Answer (score 2):

Упоминается у Ушакова (пометка: обл.) и Ефремовой (разг., сниж.), т.е. это просторечие. Мне когда-то приходилось слышать это слово, но давно; вероятно, оно подзабыто и лучше сохранилось в каком-нибудь из региональных говоров. Литературный вариант - "наги**б**аться".

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/867602

**P.S.** В форумах ссылаются на украинский язык (там вариант с "-н-" - единственный) и южные говоры (Краснодарский край). Возможно, в Киеве я когда-то и слышал.

Comment: Вариант с Н Вы имели в виду?

Comment: Я почему спросил, просто вчера один из батюшек нашего храма упомянул, что его всегда учили, что надо говорить "наги**б**аться", однако у Лескова он постоянно встречает "наги**н**аться". Я и подумал, может, во времена Лескова это и было литературным вариантом.

Comment: Да, поправил в конце на -н-. А Лесков это в прямой речи применял или в авторском тексте? Кстати, его "аглицкая" (блоха) - устаревший разговорный вариант слова "английская".

Comment: Не знаю, как употреблял. Я только повторяю его слова (он не уточнял, в прямой речи или от автора), а сам не проверял, а что читал когда-то, не помню ничего с этим словом.